# if( ( ) and ( ) ) not working

Tags: php, if-statement

The following script snippet does not seem to work and I don't know why:

```
// go to correct.php only if length between 8 and 11

$get_length = strlen( $_POST["phone"] );

if( ( $get_length >= 8 ) and ( $get_length <= 11 ) ) {
    header("Location: correct.php");
} else {
    header("Location: incorrect.php");
}
```

Even if the length is 6, it goes to correct.php.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.  Is there are proper way to check as I am definately typing in 6 nummbers into the input field which has the id phone.

Comment: `input field which has the id phone.` what? It must have the `name='phone'` php does not recognize id

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have said id instead of name.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any trailing spaces or additional characters in your input field?

Comment: Your syntax was correct. With `and` even the parens were extraneous. But your code tests for a minimum of **8** characters, where you just wrote `definitely typing in 6 nummbers`. User error.

Comment: @oshirowanen: *"...I should have said id instead of name."* If the field really has an `id` of "phone" and not a `name` of "phone", that could be part of your problem. It's the `name`, not `id`, that gets sent with the POST data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `*AND*`, `*and*` and `*&&*` is the same*. You have to debug your variable:

```
var_dump($get_length);
```

or maybe even better:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

* = in this case. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: They're not *quite* the same, as @Mark pointed out to me in a comment on an earlier answer. Their precedence is different: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php Wouldn't matter for the OP's question, though.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of question which can be answered by the programmer only.
In fact, *most* of questions a programmer have to deal with, are of this kind.
A technique that lets to get an answer is called **debugging**
The main goal of debugging is to get as much info as possible - all posible error messages, and - most important part - **actual values of variables.**.
By watching your code you have no idea of the actual values. But by running it and making it print values, you can see what's going on and guess the reasons or ask proper question on stackoverflow.

Make your code this way and post here result:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<pre>";

$get_length = strlen( $_POST["phone"] );

var_dump( $_POST["phone"],$get_length);

if( ( $get_length >= 8 ) and ( $get_length <= 11 ) ) {
    echo ("Location: correct.php");
} else {
    echo ("Location: incorrect.php");
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is working correctly.

Please check the data in $_POST.

Is it same as you are saying?

use echo $_POST['phone'] to check the real value of stirng and count the length.

Comment: How does PHP interpret the `and`, than?  `||`?

Comment: `and` would appear to be a valid operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Why? `and` is perfectly valid in PHP.

Comment: @All : sorry for that mistake. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `$_POST["phone"]` is not set.

Debug your script as follows:

1. Check if the `<form>` contains element with `name="phone"`

`<input type="text" name="phone">`

1. Check the form action and method too it should point to the file where your code is placed to check length. form method should be `post`.
2. Check it the `$_POST['phone']` is set by  `var_dump($_POST)`

After following above debugging step you will get where is the issue.

Your If condition is okeay and does not have any issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try using "&&" instead of "and".

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_operators.asp

Comment: The more canonical reference suggests `and` is valid: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php (w3schools is frequently out of date and/or incomplete, in my experience)

Answer (score -2):

try ?:

```
if( ( $get_length >= 8 ) && ( $get_length <= 11 ) ) {
```

Comment: `and` would appear to be a valid synonym: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - && and AND are not synonyms, because they have different precedence. In this case, precedence has no effect, because both test conditions are in brackets; but if they weren't bracketed, then this would result in different behaviour

Comment: @Mark: Thanks! (I'm not much of a PHP-head.) For reference if anyone's interested: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: OP's question does not have issue with precedence http://codepad.org/KpGEtJLK  so that is not the answer

Comment: @Mark nope, if they weren't bracketed, the result will remain the same